# Is it possible to split an array and inject the splits back in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ok what I need is a little weird and goes as follows:

Clues array is created manually, Data array is created dynamically. An Xpath function takes our clues as input and maps the results to data to create a dynamic array

```
clues = Array.new

clues << 'Power supply type'    
clues << 'Slots'
clues << 'Software included'

selector = "//td[text()='%s']/following-sibling::td"

data = Array.new
data = clues.map do |clue| 
         xpath = selector % clue
         [clue, doc.at(xpath).text.strip]
       end
```

The code in the data array uses two inputs, clues and selector
every item at clues[index] goes into selector at %s to become

```
//td[text()='%s']/following-sibling::td  
//td[text()='Power supply type']/following-sibling::td
//td[text()='Slots']/following-sibling::td
//td[text()='Software included']/following-sibling::td
```

Xpath then goes off and grabs information from a webpage using our stored commands, all of this is then stored as elements in the array data as data[0]...data[3]

Data[2] looks like this, a big chunk of information

```
Symantec Norton Internet Security (60 days live update); Recovery partition (inc
luding possibility to recover system; applications and drivers separately); Opti
onal re-allocation of recovery partition;
```

I want to take each piece of software listed here and store it on its own e.g.

```
data[2]Symantec Norton Internet Security (60 days live update); 
data[3]Recovery partition (including possibility to recover system; 
data[4]Optional re-allocation of recovery partition;
```

So I assume I need to split data[2] somehow and add it back into the data array?

I am trying to isolate this particular index as I need it on multiple lines for my final output to spreadsheet

**Final Desired output**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = Array.new
clues.each do |clue|
  xpath = selector % clue
  text = doc.at(xpath).text.strip
  if clue == 'Software included'
    values = text.scan(/.+?;/)
    values << text if values.empty? # text did not contain a semicolon
    data << [clue, values.shift.strip]
    values.each do |value|
      data << ['', value.strip]
    end
  else
    data << [clue, text]
  end
end
```

Output (indented to be more readable):

```
[
  ["Power supply type", "400w"],
  ["Slots", "2"],
  ["Software included", "Symantec Norton Internet Security (60 days live update);"],
  ["", "Recovery partition (including possibility to recover system;"],
  ["", "applications and drivers separately);"],
  ["", "Optional re-allocation of recovery partition;"]
]
```

Comment: I have updated the question to explain the steps in more detail.

Comment: I've fixed a bug in my answer.  The data array doesn't contain just the values, it also contains the clues in your (and my) code.  So `data[2]` is not just `'Symantec Norton Internet Security (60 days live update)'`, it's `['Software included', 'Symantec Norton Internet Security (60 days live update)']`.  I'm assuming that is what you wanted, since you had `[clue, doc.at(xpath).text.strip]` in your code.

Comment: close! however it causes formatting problems for me ;( See screens in main answer for my desired format.

Comment: Updated the code to return the desired format - don't even need `flatten()`.  Still gets rid of semicolons in software though, not sure if you need them.

Comment: Will need semicolons! which is why I thought it may be a good idea to take out the data[2] results (Software included) split them and put them back into the array, essentially allowing us to target a specific part of the array without the need to operate on anything else. What do you think?

Comment: I changed it to include semicolons (use `scan()` instead of `split()`) and to only break it down when `clue == 'Software included'` .  However, I noticed that there's another issue - one of the software rows in your spreadsheet includes a semicolon in the middle: `Recovery partition (including possibility to recover system; applications and drivers separately);`.  If you want that on a single line, you'll need better parsing than just looking for semicolons.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify, you have an array like this:

```
data << 'Power supply type'
data << 'Slots'
data << 'Symantec Norton Internet Security (60 days live update); Recovery partition (inc luding possibility to recover system; applications and drivers separately); Optional re-allocation of recovery partition;'
data << 'Something else'
```

And you want it become this?

```
data << 'Power supply type'
data << 'Slots'
data << Symantec Norton Internet Security (60 days live update);
data << Recovery partition (inc luding possibility to recover system;
data << applications and drivers separately);
data << Optional re-allocation of recovery partition;
data << 'Something else'
```

You can do this by doing the following:

```
temp = []
data[2].split(/(;)/).each_slice(2){ |s| temp << s.join.strip }
data[2] = temp
data.flatten!
```

Or if you want to iterate over all items in the data array:

```
data.each_with_index do |x, i|
  temp = []
  data[i].split(/(;)/).each_slice(2){ |s| temp << s.join.strip }
  data[i] = temp
end
data.flatten!
```

Basically what is happening is that it takes the string, splits it up on the ';', re-inserts the ';' where it was removed, replaces the original spot in the data array with the array of the split string, then flattens the entire data array back into one array.

Comment: I have updated the question to explain the steps in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = data[0..1] + data[2].scan(/.*?;/) + data[3..-1]
```